# Combination "Tamper Proof", "GFCI", and "AFCI" receptacle locations?

Tags: electrical

Where "Tamper Proof", "GFCI", and "AFCI" receptacles are required in the same space, how is that accomplished? Is there such a thing as Tamper proof GFCI or Tamper proof AFCI receptacles?

Comment: Are you asking for both GFCI and AFCI in the same receptacle, or for TR in combination with either GFCI or AFCI?

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

- An arc-fault circuit interrupter (AFCI) breaker, a tamper resistant (TR) ground-fault circuit interrupter (GFCI) receptacle, and standard TR receptacles.
- An AFCI breaker, a standalone GFCI device, and standard TR receptacles.
- A dual function circuit interrupter (DFCI), and standard TR receptacles.

### NOTES:

- There are rules about where an ACFI device can be installed in a circuit, so I'm not sure an AFCI receptacle would work in all situations.
- You should be able to find standard, GFCI, and AFCI tamper resistant receptacles. I'm not sure if a dual function receptacle is available at all, but who knows what the future holds.

Comment: You can install a faceless GFCI or AFCI receptacle in a dual gang outlet with the load going to the other device. Or install the AFCI receptacle upstream of the GFCI in a location where the GFCI isn't required (outside of the wet area). http://www.amazon.com/Bryant-Electric-GFBFST20W-Commercial-Residential/dp/B00Z9MV18Y/ref=dp_ob_title_hi

Comment: This assumes they need dual AFCI and GFCI at the same receptacle which I wasn't clear was the requirement when reading the question.

Comment: The "faceless" option lets you chain two devices at one outlet so you can get dual protection without replacing the breaker. That said, I prefer the breaker option.

Comment: @BMitch The location of AFCI devices is not so simple.

Comment: +1 Three cheers for the dual function breakers! I installed them in a reno project for an added bathroom, laundry room and mudroom (3 circuits) and have had no problems for 6 months. They cost more (about $50 apiece) but simplify the rest of the wiring and are cheaper in the long run than several specialty receptacles.